# Toggle table rows without specific link

Tags: php, jquery

I have a table with some rows, It's somewhat hard to show you all the code but I will give you an example:

```
<tr id="<?=$row['slug'];?>" class="gradeX <? if($row['parent_name']!=''){?>child<?}?>">
<td id="<?=$row['id'];?>" class="expand-parent"><? if($row['parent_name']==''){?>+<?}?></td>
<td><span id="<?=$row['id'];?>" class="edit-title"><?=$row['title'];?></td>
<td><span id="<?=$row['id'];?>" class="edit-slug"><?=$row['slug'];?></td>
<td><span id="<?=$row['id'];?>" class="edit-parent"><? if($row['parent_name']){ ?><?=$row['parent_name'];?> (ID: <?=$row['parent'];?>)<? } ?></td>
<td id="<?=$row['id'];?>" class="edit-uri"><?=$row['uri'];?></td>
<td id="<?=$row['id'];?>" class="edit-perms"><?=$row['perms'];?></td>
<td>    
<div class="toggle-button" data-toggleButton-style-enabled="success">
<input type="checkbox" class="toggle-perm" id="<?=$row['id'];?>"<?=$cl;?> />
</div>
</td>
</tr>
```

This is in a loop, and produces a few  hundred "Parent" rows, and a few thousand "Child" rows.

I have some jquery that looks like this:

```
$('.child').toggle();
            $('.expand-parent').click(function(){
                $(this).closest(".child").toggle();
            });
```

Basically what I am trying to do is once you trigger the `.expand-parent` click function, it will toggle (show) the children belonging to the parent which was clicked. What would be the best way to tell jQuery which `tr` children belong to each `tr` parent and toggle accordingly?

**EDIT**

HTML Example Output:

```
                                    <!-- Table row -->
                    <tr id="pp" class="gradeX ">
                        <td id="1" class="expand-parent">+</td>
                        <td><span id="1" class="edit-title">Prospector</td>
                        <td><span id="1" class="edit-slug">pp</td>
                        <td><span id="1" class="edit-parent"></td>
                        <td id="1" class="edit-uri"></td>
                        <td id="1" class="edit-perms"></td>
                        <td>    
                            <div class="toggle-button" data-toggleButton-style-enabled="success">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="toggle-perm" id="1" checked />
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- // Table row END -->

                                        <!-- Table row -->
                    <tr id="pp_data_providers" class="gradeX child">
                        <td id="2" class="expand-parent"></td>
                        <td><span id="2" class="edit-title">Data Providers</td>
                        <td><span id="2" class="edit-slug">pp_data_providers</td>
                        <td><span id="2" class="edit-parent">Prospector (ID: 1)</td>
                        <td id="2" class="edit-uri">/plugins/plg_prospector/prospect_providers.php</td>
                        <td id="2" class="edit-perms"></td>
                        <td>    
                            <div class="toggle-button" data-toggleButton-style-enabled="success">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="toggle-perm" id="2" checked />
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- // Table row END -->

                                        <!-- Table row -->
                    <tr id="pp_provider_lists" class="gradeX child">
                        <td id="3" class="expand-parent"></td>
                        <td><span id="3" class="edit-title">Provider Lists</td>
                        <td><span id="3" class="edit-slug">pp_provider_lists</td>
                        <td><span id="3" class="edit-parent">Prospector (ID: 1)</td>
                        <td id="3" class="edit-uri">/plugins/plg_prospector/prospect_lists.php</td>
                        <td id="3" class="edit-perms"></td>
                        <td>    
                            <div class="toggle-button" data-toggleButton-style-enabled="success">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="toggle-perm" id="3" checked />
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- // Table row END -->

                                        <!-- Table row -->
                    <tr id="pp_partners" class="gradeX child">
                        <td id="4" class="expand-parent"></td>
                        <td><span id="4" class="edit-title">Partners</td>
                        <td><span id="4" class="edit-slug">pp_partners</td>
                        <td><span id="4" class="edit-parent">Prospector (ID: 1)</td>
                        <td id="4" class="edit-uri">/plugins/plg_prospector/prospect_partners.php</td>
                        <td id="4" class="edit-perms"></td>
                        <td>    
                            <div class="toggle-button" data-toggleButton-style-enabled="success">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="toggle-perm" id="4" checked />
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- // Table row END -->

                                        <!-- Table row -->
                    <tr id="pp_reporting" class="gradeX child">
                        <td id="5" class="expand-parent"></td>
                        <td><span id="5" class="edit-title">Reporting</td>
                        <td><span id="5" class="edit-slug">pp_reporting</td>
                        <td><span id="5" class="edit-parent">Prospector (ID: 1)</td>
                        <td id="5" class="edit-uri"></td>
                        <td id="5" class="edit-perms"></td>
                        <td>    
                            <div class="toggle-button" data-toggleButton-style-enabled="success">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="toggle-perm" id="5" />
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- // Table row END -->

                                        <!-- Table row -->
                    <tr id="pp_campaigns" class="gradeX child">
                        <td id="6" class="expand-parent"></td>
                        <td><span id="6" class="edit-title">Campaigns</td>
                        <td><span id="6" class="edit-slug">pp_campaigns</td>
                        <td><span id="6" class="edit-parent">Prospector (ID: 1)</td>
                        <td id="6" class="edit-uri">/plugins/plg_prospector/prospect_campaigns.php</td>
                        <td id="6" class="edit-perms"></td>
                        <td>    
                            <div class="toggle-button" data-toggleButton-style-enabled="success">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="toggle-perm" id="6" checked />
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- // Table row END -->

                                        <!-- Table row -->
                    <tr id="cbm" class="gradeX ">
                        <td id="7" class="expand-parent">+</td>
                        <td><span id="7" class="edit-title">CBM</td>
                        <td><span id="7" class="edit-slug">cbm</td>
                        <td><span id="7" class="edit-parent"></td>
                        <td id="7" class="edit-uri"></td>
                        <td id="7" class="edit-perms"></td>
                        <td>    
                            <div class="toggle-button" data-toggleButton-style-enabled="success">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="toggle-perm" id="7" checked />
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- // Table row END -->
```

Comment: This might be a lot easier with a nested table structure instead of using classes to define parent/child rows.  Then you can just reference the `table` that's nested inside the `td`.

Comment: Can you post some of the HTML which is the output from the php code?

Comment: Edited with example HTML output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On rows which have a parent I would add an attribute containing the parent id.

Example:

```
<tr id="cbm" class="gradeX" data-parentid="1">
```

Then you can write the jQuery event like this:

```
var $this = $(this);
var id = $this.attr('id');
$(this).parents('table').find('tr[data-parentid='+id+']').toggle();
```

Notes:
parents('table') to traverse to the table element
find(..) locate all tr elements with the attribute data-parentid set to id.

It's illegal to have multiple elements with the same id so I would get rid of them. The cleanest way would be to move it to the tr element.